# xml from excel with 3 identical groups - convert to one repeating group

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I am a newby at XML and XSLT. I have searched for something similar in the forum without success. Is the follow translation possible with XSLT? It is basically an XML derived from an Excel spreadsheet, which has 3 groups which are identical repeated on the same row, so they have different names, group1, …2 and …3, which I want to make into one group repeated 3 times if there is data in them. The example below is a simplified version:

```
<application> 
    <group1>
        <name1>John</name1>
    </group1>
    <group2>
        <name2>Mary</name2>
    </group2>
    <group3>
        <name3>Peter</name3>
    </group3>
</application>
```

convert to

```
<application> 
    <group ref="001">
        <line_no>001</line_no>
        <name>John</name>
    </group>
    <group ref="002">
        <line_no>002</line_no>
        <name>Mary</name>
    </group>
    <group ref="003">
        <line_no>003</line_no>
        <name>Peter</name>
    </group>
</application>
```

Excel does not lend itself to exporting to XML in any but the most simple way.

Comment: @user736437: Should we get numbers from names or document order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One stylesheet could be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'group')]">
        <group ref="{format-number(substring-after(name(),'group'),'000')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'name')]">
        <line_no>
            <xsl:value-of
             select="format-number(substring-after(name(),'name'),'000')"/>
        </line_no>
        <name>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </name>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<application>
    <group ref="001">
        <line_no>001</line_no>
        <name>John</name>
    </group>
    <group ref="002">
        <line_no>002</line_no>
        <name>Mary</name>
    </group>
    <group ref="003">
        <line_no>003</line_no>
        <name>Peter</name>
    </group>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Alejandro, I will try that on my more complex problem and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Xslt has a `position()` function. This should help you get the number in front of the name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks adymitruk. Your help is appreciated.